porqué no puede acceder a la carpeta contenida en el directorio raiz?

En esta primera imagen no se muestra la carpeta resources al que necesito acceder para leer unos archivos txt a los que al intentarlo me da el error 404 como en la anterior imagen

Sin embargo, dentro del proyecto que estoy desarrollando en netbeans deberia poder accederse ya que es a esta carpeta que intento llegar

concluyo que no es un error de código ya que en otra prueba con un programa similar me permite acceder, solo que no tenia este mismo ordenamiento.
Considerando que la carpeta resources a la que intento acceder fue creada de forma manual, a diferencia de "grupo_M1" 3 y 3 que fueron creados por un mkdir con permisos 0777 ¿Porqué el navegador no puede acceder a la misma?

uso XAMPP para el servidor local y netbeans para escribir el código, el archivo sí existe, se crea mediante la función fopen($nombre_archivo, "w") para luego cerrarlo, le asigno un formato txt al mismo, está alojado en resources/grupos/grupo_M1 por dar un ejemplo ya que la ruta se define a partir de un id del div contenedor del submenu y otro id del div de visualizacion por lo que la ruta se está definiendo correctamente

de hecho, la subcarpeta también existe al igual que el archivo llamado, se forma la ruta completa y se define el nombre del archivo necesario pero por alguna razón no la encuentra. Además, hay otros dos archivos alojados en la misma carpeta resources que sí se están encontrando

De nuevo, MIRA EL ERROR, el código está buscando el archivo en un directorio que existe, pero el archivo dentro del directorio no. Tu subcarpeta generada, se genera bien, pero no está incluida al momento de buscar el archivo, sea como sea que lo estás llamando, por que no agregaste nada de ese código.

este es el código que se supone que genera la ruta al archivo: setTimeout(() => {
var caso = $('.caja_speech:visible').prop('id');
var menu = $('.menus:visible').prop('id');
var ruta = "/resources/grupos/" + menu + "/" + caso + ".txt";
$.ajax({
url: ruta,
dataType: "text",
success: function (data)
{
$(".caja_speech").html("" + data + "");
}
});
}, 100);

Ahi dice /resources/grupos/, y luego el archivo .txt ... Agrega todo el fragmento al código, pero parece que por ahí va tu problema. Ahora, como le pasas la carpeta generada a ese código ?

Continuemos el debate en el chat.

El error del usuario, menciona un problema con las rutas, simplemente, no encuentra el archivo. Pero el error no se mostraba completo y consulté por chat con el.
Luego de consultar por chat con el usuario.
Obtuvimos el error actualizado:

El error menciona que la URL generada, está buscando directamente del siguiente modo:
http://localhost/resources/grupos/....txt

Esto, es un problema con las rutas.
EL código que el OP usa para generar la URL, era el siguiente:
setTimeout(() => {
    var caso = $('.caja_speech:visible').prop('id');
    var menu = $('.menus:visible').prop('id');
    var ruta = "/resources/grupos/" + menu + "/" + caso + ".txt";

    $.ajax({
        url: ruta,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
            $(".caja_speech").html("<pre id='texto'>" + data + "</pre>");
        }
    });
}, 100);

Dentro de este código, no está añadida la carpeta del proyecto, que es "prueba3", entonces la modificación es simple:
var ruta = "/prueba3/resources/grupos/" + menu + "/" + caso + ".txt";

Con este simple cambio, se logró corregir la URL del usuario, y que el código pudiese encontrar el archivo.
